# failed to authenticate on smtp server in laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, cpanel, centos7, whm

when i am trying to send mails using smtp in laravel application i am having this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8p8q.png)

i thought the error is is app but when i upload app on another server the mails are going good.
but on the centos server which is having cpanel is facing this error while sending mail. even i have disabled smtp restrictions in whm.

i am using a laravel application to send email . to sending mails i amd adding smtp server. when i start sending mail 2000 mails get sent but after that all mails gets blocked and are not sent out of the server

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using queue?

Try to change your mail driver from `smtp` to `mail`